# Maintain event height during drag or resize

Tags: fullcalendar-scheduler

I'd like to have my events in scheduler whose height is 27 px to visually maintain that height while resizing or dragging. Currently it shrinks down to a fraction of its original size and users hate this. Can this be done? I'd like to just adjust the css if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share an image of the problem and some of the CSS code you done.

Comment: Found the issue, I was setting the height with css $(element).css('height','100%');.  I found if I used the property eventOverlap it fixed my issue. eventOverlap: false, // will cause the event to take up entire resource height